# ¿Cómo encriptar una base de datos SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqlite3

Necesito encriptar una base de datos en `SQLite`¿Existe algún software que permita encriptar una DB `SQLite`? Los datos que va a contener son privados y quiero que se mantenga su integridad.

Comment: chequea esta tool: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/open-source/

Comment: Revisa este link http://stackoverflow.com/a/23312036/2026740

Comment: Existen varias opciones, no tengo tiempo de agregar una respuesta, te dejo lo que uso: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/

Answer (score 4):

SQLite tiene complementos integradas para el cifrado que no se utilizan en la distribución normal, pero aquí hay algunas implementaciones:

- [SEE](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html) - La implementación oficial.
- [wxSQLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxsqlite/) - wxWidgets estilo complemento C++ que también implementa el cifrado en SQLite.
- [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/) - Usa openSSL libcrypto para implementarlo.
- [SQLiteCrypt](http://sqlite-crypt.com/documentation.htm) - Implementación personalizada, API modificado.
- [botansqlite3](https://github.com/OlivierJG/botansqlite3) - Es un códec de cifrado para SQLite3 que puede utilizar cualquier algoritmo de cifrado Botan.
- [SQLiteCrypto](http://www.andbrain.com/product/sqlitecrypto/) - SQLiteCrypto es al vía más fácil para encritar Sqlite Database con AES-256 y SHA-256

SEE, SQLiteCrypt y SQLiteCrypto requieren pagar licencia.

> Traducción al español a la pregunta [SQLite with encryption/password protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669905/sqlite-with-encryption-password-protection) en stack**overflow** por [olijg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502789/olijg).

Answer (score 0):

Personalmente he usado [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) y te puedo hablar por experiencia propia.

El **PROS** ya lo sabemos, tu base de datos estará cifrada y relativamente segura ante cualquier intrusión

Otro punto a favor que tiene esta librería es que migrar tu código es muy sencillo.

Los cambios en tu codigo pueden ser tan simples como reemplazar un `import` de `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase` a `net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase`, realmente es bastante sencillo.

Ahora, los **CONS** para mí serían los siguientes, y les llamo *CONS* solo para referirme a estos aspectos que son sumamente importantes y los debes tener en cuenta.

1. El peso de tu APK va a aumentar considerablemente, de manera similar cuando tu instalación se ejecute en el dispositivo del usuario; el crecimiento será directamente proporcional. Por ejemplo: mi aplicación sin SQLCipher pesa 2.85MB, con SQLCipher pesa 7.65MB
   Si te fijas en la documentación para [Android](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/), verás que debes hacer uso de varios archivos y ninguno puede omitirse.
2. Tu aplicación puede ponerse muuuy lenta, para evitar esto debes revisar que tus accesos a base de datos son óptimos. El abrir y cerrar una conexión a la base de datos para cada transacción es desastroso cuando encriptas una base de datos, no solo con esta herramienta si no con cualquiera; incluso es muy dañino aún para bases de datos sin cifrar. La clave es abrir/cerrar conexiones en reducido numero de veces, solo cuando sea necesario y establecer transacciones pesadas en bloques.
3. Cuando tengas tu base de datos cifrada (y si tienes la necesidad de hacerlo) deberás crear una forma de poder ver de manera plana (sin cifrar) la propia base de datos, esto por si quieres debuggear, confirmar datos, etc. cosas que hace uno como desarrollador para validar que todo anda bien.

Como posdata, solo mencionar que es importante respetar la distribución de las carpetas que se presenta en la guía de configuración, específicamente para los ficheros:

- cudt46l.zip
- la propia lib (*.jar)
- carpeta **armeabi**

Espero te sirva.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mi base de datos ya esta hecha, con esta libreria se pudiera encriptar porque estuve viendo ejemplos y es con base de datos nueva.

Comment: Puedes encriptar una base de datos hecha, no hay ningún problema con ello Pablo.